# Page broken in IE8 only

Tags: templates, internet-explorer-8

I have a page that is having problems, but only on IE8. A grid of images isn't displaying correctly.

I wondered if anyone might be able to shed any light on what is going wrong?

I have made a few css changes but have restored it back to the original. The only change is therefore an extra div (but since I put the css back, it has no styling).

Its a wp template running on 3.4.2. I have tried contacting the developer (several times) but am not getting any reply.

I am at a bit of a loss and if anyone could help I'd be very greatful

The page is at http://www.haywardsdrycleaners.com/services/

Comment: have now removed that div in case it was inheriting - no change.

Comment: and have discovered that there is a nesting error in how the tags are generating. When I remove this error from a html copy of the page things work. So that's a start - I guess that for some reason only IE8 threw its hands up with said error.